# Debian randomly changes IP adress

Tags: debian, routing, network-interface

I have debian6, interfaces are set manually:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 40:61:86:7c:42:ed
          inet addr:192.168.3.238  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4261:86ff:fe7c:42ed/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25460712 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15936414 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:20505323410 (19.0 GiB)  TX bytes:3909617144 (3.6 GiB)
          Interrupt:25
```

This machine is used as DHCP server (isc-dhcp-server) and DNS forwarder (bind9) and shorewall.

Recently and randomly itself changes IP address for `eth0` to 192.168.0.1 or even removes IP settings completely. I cant then connect internet from that machine or any other machine on local network.

What can I do to stop this behaviour? How to track service responsible for this?

Content of interfaces

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.3.238
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.3.1

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.0.0.1
    netmask 255.0.0.0
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

Report from `syslog`

```
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian avahi-daemon[2189]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.3.238 on eth0.
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian avahi-daemon[2189]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv4 with address 192.168.3.238.
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian avahi-daemon[2189]: Interface eth0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian kernel: [1107087.393431] martian source 10.0.40.1 from 10.0.40.167, on dev eth0
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian kernel: [1107087.393439] ll header: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:4f:67:03:b0:1f:08:06
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian kernel: [1107087.901047] martian source 10.0.40.1 from 10.0.40.185, on dev eth0
Mar 15 10:44:22 debian kernel: [1107087.901056] ll header: ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:1e:58:0d:08:df:08:06
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: All rights reserved.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient:
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 19: no option named domain-nameserver in space dhcp
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: supersede domain-nameserver 10.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient:            ^
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 20: semicolon expected.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: prepend
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient:  ^
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/40:61:86:7c:42:ed
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/40:61:86:7c:42:ed
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on eth0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian avahi-daemon[2189]: Interface eth0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian avahi-daemon[2189]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface eth0.IPv6 with address fe80::4261:86ff:fe7c:42ed.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian avahi-daemon[2189]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4261:86ff:fe7c:42ed on eth0.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian kernel: [1107088.283819] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian kernel: [1107088.283839] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian kernel: [1107088.284456] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: All rights reserved.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient:
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 19: no option named domain-nameserver in space dhcp
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: supersede domain-nameserver 10.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient:            ^
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf line 20: semicolon expected.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: prepend
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient:  ^
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth0/40:61:86:7c:42:ed
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth0/40:61:86:7c:42:ed
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on eth0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: send_packet: Network is unreachable
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian dhclient: send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address.
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian kernel: [1107088.401716] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
Mar 15 10:44:23 debian kernel: [1107088.402152] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Mar 15 10:44:24 debian dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.1.1-P1
Mar 15 10:44:24 debian dhclient: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Mar 15 10:44:24 debian dhclient: All rights reserved.
Mar 15 10:44:24 debian dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Mar 15 10:44:24 debian dhclient:
```

Comment: The first thing I would verify is that you aren't accidentally running the interface in DHCP mode. Is NetworkManager or something similar running, and what are the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: This debian has also xfce window manager, not sure if that has some network manager which can overwrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your syslog / dmesg say? A change of IP address should result in an entry in the log file. This might give you a hint what caused it (i.e. the couple of lines before the IP change).

For instance, if you manually restart networking, something like this pops up in dmesg / syslog

```
[47460.471835] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[47460.473570] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link down
[47460.475690] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[47463.368498] r8169 0000:09:00.0: eth0: link up
[47463.370603] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: I added recent syslog report when connection got dropped again.

Comment: Is it possible that your box loses physical network connectivity? This is my current guess from reading your logs. I don't see a eth0: link becomes ready in your log file, hence I assume debian believes your eth0 is disconnected.

Comment: No, it is very unlikely. Everytime I restart interface it just connects immediately. As I am using network from local network computer I am able to immediately restart networking and it works immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The clue from your syslog is that you have dhclient and avahi running. For a server with static configuration it is best practice to apt-get remove avahi-daemon and network-manager. You can configure avahi not to interfere with eth0 but its just not worth the bother.

After you remove avahi and network manager, reboot and run `ps ax` to verify that `dhclient*` and `avahi*` not running.

Comment: I have removed them, I will wait for a day or two see whether it stopped.